# Ensuring a <p> sits underneath a div

Tags: php, css, html

I am having great difficulty in placing a line of text directly underneath a div. Just so you under stand or can picture my code, the div contains an image pulled from my database and the users first and last name is also pulled but sits under the image. I hope this explains the following:

```
 <div id="latest">
    <?php 
        $query = 'SELECT f.*, m.firstname AS firstname, m.lastname AS lastname FROM folio AS f, members AS m WHERE f.userid = m.id ORDER BY dateadded DESC';
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        if(!$result){
            die('Database error: '.mysqli_error($connection));
        }
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            ?>
    <a href="#inline1" style="text-decoration:none;" class="fancybox" >
    <div class="outimgbox"> <a style="text-decoration: none;" class="fancybox fancybox.ajax" rel="gallery<?php echo $row['userid']; ?>" data-fancybox-type="ajax" href="profile_image_fancybox.php?imgid=<?php echo $row['imgid']; ?>">
      <div id="mainwrapper">
        <div id="box-3" class="box"> <img class="uploads"  src="uploads/folio/<?php echo $row['filename']; ?>" /> <span class="caption fade-caption">
          <h3><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h3>
          <p style="color: #2d2d2d; font-size: 12px; padding-left:2px; text-decoration: none;"><?php echo 'by' ."&nbsp;". $row['firstname'] ."&nbsp;". $row['lastname'];  ?></p>
          </span> </div>
      </div>
      </a> </div>
        <p>
            <?php echo 'by' ."&nbsp;". $row['firstname'] ."&nbsp;". $row['lastname'];  ?>
        </p>
    <?
        }
        ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

As requested here is the css:

```
    img.uploads{padding: 0;
        margin-left: -25%;
        max-height:100%;
        }


    img.uploads:hover{
        opacity: .4;
        -webkit-transition: opacity;
        -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 1000ms;
    }

    #mainwrapper {
}

/* Image Box Style */
#mainwrapper .box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border:10px solid #fff;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #d9d9d9;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #d9d9d9;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #d9d9d9;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
        cursor:pointer;

}
#mainwrapper .box img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
        -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
        -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
        -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
        -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out; 
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;

}

/* Caption Common Style */
#mainwrapper .box .caption {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.95);
    position: absolute;
    color: #2d2d2d;
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out; 
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    left: 0;
}


/** Caption 3: Fade **/
#mainwrapper .box .fade-caption, #mainwrapper .box .scale-caption  {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 231px;
    height: 231px;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 15px;
}


#mainwrapper .box .scale-caption h3 {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 300ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 300ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 300ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 300ms;    
    transition-delay: 300ms;
}

#mainwrapper .box .scale-caption p {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 500ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 500ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 500ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 500ms;    
    transition-delay: 500ms;
}


/** Fade Caption :hover Behaviour **/
#mainwrapper .box:hover .fade-caption, #mainwrapper .box:hover .scale-caption  {
    opacity: 1;
}


#mainwrapper .box:hover .scale-caption h3, #mainwrapper .box:hover .scale-caption p {
    -moz-transform: translateX(200px);
    -o-transform: translateX(200px);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(200px);
    transform: translateX(200px);
}
```

Comment: Or better yet provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that demonstrates the problem

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vxeTC/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot wrong with your code. 
 
First, you have a **h3** between the image and **p**. 
Second, you make a **span** the container for **p**. 
What you are trying to achieve isn't possible under that setting and validation of your code will not be possible either. 
Try something like this instead:

```
 
  <div id="box-3" class="box"> 
   <h3><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h3>
   <p>
    <img class="uploads"  src="uploads/folio/" />
   </p>
   <p id="whatever" style="color: #2d2d2d; font-size: 12px; padding-left:2px; text-decoration: none;">
   <?php echo 'by' ." ". $row['firstname'] ." ". $row['lastname'];  ?>
  </p>
 </div>
```

Then, simply style it like this:

```
 
   .box-3 p{margin: 0; padding: 0;}
   #whatever{display: none;} /* this will hide the names by default */
   .box-3:hover #whatever{display: block;} /* this should resolve your issue */
```

This will remove all the empty spaces between the two **p** and the text will be right under the image (as long as the image doesn't have any padding or margin either). 
 
Hope the explanation is clear and the answer helps.

Comment: Sorry I must not be explaining myself, I want first name and last name to appear underneath when you hover over the  image as currently they appear inside the div when it fades over the images, so I want the names to fade in on the hover underneath...

Comment: I can update the answer to make the names not display by default. However, making them display on image hover can't be done via CSS; you have to use JavaScript. Check my answer update to make the names invisible by default.

Comment: If you check out my jsfiddle it does appear on top of the image on hover but I want it to be underneath the image. I am not too fussed about it appearing on hover from nowhere when I think about it.

Comment: Thank you this worked. I really appreciate the time you gave me, that goes to everyone!

Answer (score 1):

It's the span-element following the image that messes things up. You need to wrap the image and the following text in block-level elements. You can use div (or figure and figcaption if you're into html5).

Comment: Could you show me an example by editing my fiddle perhaps? I have tried numerous things but still unable to achieve the end result.jsfiddle.net/vxeTC/1

Comment: Just so i understand correctly: is it the last name paragraph you want to line up under the image div or is it the text inside the wrapper?

Comment: It is me not explaining correctly, I did initially want the name on top so when you hover it clouds the image out and the name appears, but I would like the name to sit underneath the image and appear still when you hover over the image div,

Comment: Okay; give me a second to update the solution. I think I have something to help.

Answer (score 1):

I think Whistletoe means something like this. Replace the span with a div, since you don't want it on the same line, right?

```
<div id="mainwrapper">
    <div id="box-3" class="box">
        <img class="uploads"  src="uploads/folio/<?php echo $row['filename']; ?>" />
        <div class="caption fade-caption">
            <h3><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h3>
            <p style="color: #2d2d2d; font-size: 12px; padding-left:2px; text-decoration: none;"><?php echo 'by' ."&nbsp;". $row['firstname'] ."&nbsp;". $row['lastname'];  ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: One thing has been cured from your code and that is now the users name is now a link, however the names still sits to the right of the image...

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using 'float' on the '#mainwrapper .box', you need to have 'clear: left' if you want elements to appear underneath instead of on the side.

Example:

Html:

```
<div class="float">
    ...
</div>

<p class="clear">
    ...
</p>
```

Css:

```
.float { width: 30%; float: left; }

.clear { clear: left; }
```

Comment: Do you have an example?